# What's the difference between the grape, a grape, grapes?

Tags: articles, definite-articles, indefinite-articles

I'm a non-native English speaker.

If I want to say,

"The green grape is my favorite fruit."

is it okay?
And is the sentence above different from these two?

"A green grape is my favorite fruit."
"green grapes are my favorite fruit."

Comment: Saying *the green grape* makes it seem like your are talking about just one http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/single-green-grape-21179238.jpg

Comment: If so, is "green grapes" correct?

Comment: It is the most natural wording.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic on ELU and should instead be on [ell.se].

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't know it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

*the green grape* can be used when talking about a type of grape more than any specific pile of grapes.

If you are talking about particular grapes you could point at, then *a green grape* for one or *green grapes* for more than one.

Comment: Hmmm, I started to be confused. If someone asks me "What's your favorite fruit?", which one is correct among these: "The green grape/A green grape/Green grapes (is/are my favorite fruit.), then"?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:  Say "Green grapes are my favorite fruit."

This is like asking, "What is your favorite type of TV show?"  and answering, "Sitcoms are my favorite type of TV show."  You could say, "The sitcom is my favorite type of TV show [singular], but since you watch many of them, I think it is OK to say "Sitcoms are my favorite [plural]."

Similarly, if you are asked "What is your favorite type of fruit [singular]," I think it is OK to answer "Green grapes are may favorite type of fruit [plural, since everyone eats more than one]."

Nevertheless, it is also OK to say "The green grape is my favorite type of fruit [green as opposed to red or black in the grape category]."